# MongoDB remote shell script create database

Tags: mongodb

New to this forum, to mongodb , My goal is to automate a database creation from a linux BATCH on a computer client to the server.

```
conn = new mongo();    "returns OK"
db = conn.getDB("admin"); "returns OK"
db.runCommand( { use NewDatabase } ) "returns *NOK* , this  is not the good syntax  "
```

Can't found the way in the Shell Helper , or perhaps i missed it in mongodb help:  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/

Is there is a solution or do i have to use Py -Pymongo or an another language?

Thank you, sorry for the first post i was not a really nice post.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what is not working? Do you have any errors?  If you are trying to include `use dbname` in your command-line javascript, that won't work (it's interactive syntax only). For tips see: [Write Scripts for the `mongo` Shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) and in particular note the differences between interactive and scripted mode. You might also be interested in the MongoDB manual examples discussing how to [Model Tree Structures](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/).

Comment: Sorry, i willl be more explicit. In fact : How to create a minmal javascript file

Comment: @nwk Thank's a lot for the link . Everything'work great , except create a new db, can't find the command to do that:     db._adminCommand( {use a-new-db} )'                             not working but work in interactive shell.

Comment: @nwk Thank's a lot for the link . Everything'work great , except create a new db, can't find the command to do that:     inline 'db._adminCommand( {use a-new-db} )',                            not working but work in interactive shell.

Comment: @Stennie Hi, Stennie, thank for the comment, i change the question to be more explicit, have you an idea to create a database from script, or may i have miss something in the mongo db help :}. For your information, the tree creation works fine by mongo shell, but is really difficult in pymongo there is no issue from my point of vue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to create/use a database from a command line passed to the `mongo` shell you can either:

- use the [scripted equivalent](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo) of `use NewDatabase` in your JavaScript file:

  `db = db.getSiblingDB('NewDatabase');`
- pass the database name your script should execute against on the [`mongo`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/) shell command line:

  `mongo NewDatabase foo.js`

If you don't specify a database name, `test` is the default name used by the `mongo` shell.

Comment: Work fine after test,  have to insert one document to commit DB creation.Thank's a lot , i have not seen i this behaviour in mongo doc last days.

Comment: @Zlorg Yes, the database files will not be created until you insert a document or create an index for a collection in that database.